Sufficient statistic of a function of the parameter
In Hogg and McKean's "Introduction to Mathematical statistics", there is a section ($7.6$) on functions of a parameter. Purpose is to find the MVUE of function of a parameter. He uses example $7.6.1$ as a vehicle to introduce the ideas.
Example $7.6.1.$ Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots , X_n$ denote the observations of a random sample of size $n>1$ from a distribution that is $b(1,\theta)$ (here, $b(n,\theta)$ stands for Binomial distribution), $0<\theta<1$. We know that if $Y = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, then $Y/n$ is the unique minimum variance unbiased estimator of $\theta$. Now suppose we want to estimate the variance of $Y/n,$ which is $\theta(1 − \theta)/n$. Let $δ = \theta(1−\theta)$. Because $Y$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, it is known that we can restrict our search to functions of $Y$.
The last statement is where I have a problem. He has never shown that "if $Y$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, then $Y$ is a sufficient statistic for any function of $\theta$, say $g(\theta)$.
Possible duplicates -- Post1 and Post2.
These threads were not very helpful to me in convincing myself about $Y$ also being sufficient for $g(\theta)$ for any (perhaps measurable) function $g$ especially when you try to start from his definition of sufficiency.
Please also note that he has not proven this fact (at least up until the current Section $7.6$).
Definition $7.2.1.$ Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots , X_n$ denote a random sample of size $n$ from a distribution that has pdf or pmf $f(x;\theta),$ $\theta \in \Omega$. Let $Y_1 = u_1(X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n)$ be a statistic whose pdf or pmf is $f_{Y_1}(y_1;\theta)$. Then $Y_1$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ if and only if
$$\cfrac{f(x_1;\theta)f(x_2;\theta)\cdots f(x_n;\theta)}{f_{Y_1}[u_1(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n);\theta]} = H(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$$
where $H(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ does not depend upon $\theta \in \Omega$.
Here, suppose we are given that $g(\theta) = \gamma$, and we are actually not given $\theta$ directly. So maybe, we are given that $\sin(\theta) = 1/\sqrt{2}$ which technically has infinite solutions. I can see that if we choose one of the solutions, then the definition assures us that the ratio in the LHS is independent of that particular value of $\theta$.
So in order to prove that $Y$ is sufficient for $g(\theta)$ as well, can we use the following line of argument?
Proof:
Consider the set $A_{\gamma} = g^{-1}(\gamma) = \{\theta: g(\theta) = \gamma \}$. Then for each element of $A_{\gamma}$, we can apply the definition $7.2.1.$ above and we always end up with the same ratio $H(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ in the RHS. Hence in that definition, we can replace $\theta$ with any $\gamma=g(\theta).$
Is this convincing?
Also, does $g$ have to be measurable and if so, why? (asking because I read somewhere on one of SE posts that it has to be measurable). Usually, we talk about measurability when we have a measurable space we are dealing with. But at least here, $\theta$ is just a parameter and not a random variable so I am not even sure why the question of measurability comes in when there is no context to define a measurable space.

If something depends on $g(\theta),$ then perforce it depends on $\theta$!

whuber Sir I fully agree with you. I just tried to express the same idea in some kind of a proof form. The more I study Mathematical Statistics and other rigorous math fields, the more anal retentive I am becoming about putting every thought and conclusion in the form of a mathematical proof/statement. I am losing faith on logical arguments which might require semantics in the English language. You just can't go wrong with semantics in the language of mathematical logic :).

BTW is it really crystal clear to you (given the definition $7.2.1$ of the Sufficient statistic), without putting it in the form of a proof, that any function of the parameter also has $Y$ as its sufficient statistic especially when that fact is never mentioned in the text as a theorem/lemma?

That is a truly basic property of functions.  It has nothing to do with sufficient statistics per se.

Can you please explicate $b(1, \theta)$ ? Beta? Binomial?

@kjetilbhalvorsen Sorry about that. I had copied it as is from the text where he has defined it before. I have added clarification in the text that $b(n,\theta)$ stands for Binomial distribution.

FWIW, $b(1,\theta)$ is not a Bernoulli distribution.  Are you sure you have copied the question correctly?

The question does not include the part I have in the parentheses. So I removed that part and I can only say that I inferred it from the material in the text. For instance, on page $243$ section $4.2.2$, he says "Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variables with Bernoulli distributions $b(1, p_1)$ and $b(1, p_2)$, respectively." I am cent percent sure though that $b(n,p)$ is Binomial distribution in his lingo (definition is on page $156$). Also, if you trust Wiki, they mention that too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Bernoulli_distribution

Thanks--and my apologies, for I misread "binomial" as "beta", which is entirely my fault.

@whuber Sir kindly do not apologize. It's not an issue at all :)
